# A Beamer environment that automatically warps paragraphs in \onslide<x-y>?

Tags: beamer, paragraphs, slideshow

Is there an environment in Beamer that wraps paragraphs in it with the `\onslide` command?

i.e. instead of writing this:

```
\onslide<1->{
  This is the first paragraph.
}


\onslide<2->{
  And this is the second paragraph.
}


\onslide<3->{
  And this... you get the point.
}
```

it would be possible to write something like this:

```
\begin{specialenv}
  This is the first paragraph.

  And this is the second paragraph.

  And this... you get the point. 
\end{specialenv}
```

Comment: I think a macro is required.

Comment: This is my very humble opinion, but aren't paragraphs inappropriate as a presentation content ? I mean, the less text the better in general. Also, `itemize` environments sort of do this already, if you use `\item[]` to remove the bullet

Comment: Any news on this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You could define a new environment like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newenvironment{specialenv}{
  \apptocmd{\par}{\pause}{}{}
}{}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
\begin{specialenv}
  This is the first paragraph.

  And this is the second paragraph.

  And this... you get the point. 
\end{specialenv}

test

\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]